# Understanding Python logic

Tags: python, logic, python-3.4

Using Python 3.4, wondering how does this loop processing?

```
while SyntaxError:
    print ("Hi")
```

It's an infinite loop, how does this `while` loop running? It's an exception but..?

Comment: Because the `SyntaxError` class evaluates truthy in a Boolean context. This is equivalent to `while True`, that it's an `Exception` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean value of `SyntaxError` is `True`.

```
>>> bool(SyntaxError)
True
```

That is why `while` loop is going in infinite loop because `while SyntaxError:` is equivalent to `while True:` condition.

```
while SyntaxError:
    print ("Hi")
```

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions are just objects unless they're `raise`d - `bool(SyntaxError)` is `True`, so your loop is effectively `while True:`